React and Typescript code issues (page refresh + phone compatibility)
I am coding my first website in React and Typescript. My site aims to host and display videos (like YouTube for example).
I have 2 problems that I can't solve:

Some of my pages are homepages and others are page display templates. I use router and useLocation() for communication between the two. The problem is that when a user refreshes the page on my page template, useLocation(); is empty and the user then lands on the 404 error: not found page. I would like at least the refresh to redirect to the associated homepage. Here is the code of my Template page:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Grille_video_style.css';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

//Adaptable web/phone style
const ContainerStyle = styled.div`
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  
  //Adaptation for phone
  @media (max-width: 85em) {
    width: 70%;
  }
`;


const Grille_video: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { paths } = location.state as { paths: string[] };
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState(paths);
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState<boolean>(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 85em)').matches);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
  // Back button press function
  const handleBackClick = () => {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    document.exitFullscreen().catch(err => console.log(err));
    navigate('/Grille');
  };

  // Detection of whether or not the website is used by phone
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsMobile(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 85em)').matches);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  // Disable scrolling
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  return (
    <ContainerStyle>
      <button onClick={handleBackClick} style={styles.backButton}>
        Retour
      </button>
      {videos.map((src, index) => (
        <video
          key={index}
          style={styles.videoMain}
          controls={isMobile ? selectedVideoIndex === index : true}
          autoPlay
          loop
          muted
          className="custom-video"
          preload="auto"
        >
          <source src={src} type="video/mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      ))}
    </ContainerStyle>
  );
};

const styles: { [key: string]: React.CSSProperties | any } = {
  backButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '10px',
    left: '10px',
    padding: '10px 20px',
    backgroundColor: '#EA6666',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    zIndex: 1100,
  },
  videoMain: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100vw', 
    height: 'calc(100vh - 50px)',
    objectFit: 'cover',
    opacity: 1,
    zIndex: 1000,
  },
};

export default Grille_video;


More complex problem, my website works correctly on Samsung but not on IPhone (same browser), some of my features and displays are blocked… How can I make my website compatible with all types of devices? Are there any resources on the internet that help to know what to integrate to be compatible with X phone model?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Problem 1: Handling the page refresh with useLocation()
To solve your problem, you can try saving the path in localStorage to persist the state. You can check localStorage for the paths and set it to the state if available in the useEffect()
const storedPaths = localStorage.getItem('videoPaths');
const locationPaths = location.state?.paths;

if (storedPaths) {
  setVideos(JSON.parse(storedPaths));
} else if (locationPaths) {
  setVideos(locationPaths);
  localStorage.setItem('videoPaths', JSON.stringify(locationPaths));
} else {
  navigate('/404');
}

Problem 2: CSS issues for devices
Can you try CSS Resets and Normalisation for your use case?
